# how to use the variable in one component to another component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular8

In angular application I have to use one variable which is defined in function of one component to another component

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
public nnum: string;
  public ncount: number = 0;

// some code

  addNotification(msg) {
    //const nl = document.querySelector("#notify");
    const nlnum = document.querySelector("#notificount");
    var el = document.createElement("li");
    if (msg.event == "New Signal") {
      if (wifiarray.indexOf(msg.mac) !== -1) {
        console.log("Already exists");
      } else {
        lcount = lcount + 1;
        this.ncount = lcount;
```

**nav.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotifyService } from '../../notify.service';


export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {


}
```

**nav.component.html**

```
      <li class="nav-item dropdown" ngbDropdown>
        <a class="nav-link count-indicator dropdown-toggle" id="notificationDropdown" ngbDropdownToggle>
          
          <i class="fa fa-bell">
 
</i>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger badge-up" >{{ncount}}</span>

        </a>
</li>
```

and I have the notify service
**notify.service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
export interface Message {
 
}
```

Now I want to use the ncount value from dashboard component to navbar component to to view the value .

I have tried but not working can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Please could you reformat your question. We really need to see your template code for both components first.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides **Input** and **Output** decorators to pass data **to** and **from** parent and child components. Please find the [reference link](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs).

If **DashboardComponent** is the child component of **NavComponent**, and you want to pass some variable data to its parent component, you'll have to use **Output** decorator in combination with **EventEmitter**, declared inside the class of **DashboardComponent**. You'll declare something like this:

```
@Output() myCount = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

Now wherever the value of your variable change, emit the same through this output decorator. Something like this:

```
this.ncount = lcount; //from your sample code
this.myCount.emit(ncount);
```

Now in the parent component where **DashboardComponent** is declared, you'll have to declare this output emitter property, something like this:

```
<dashboard (myCount)="countChange($event)"></dashboard>
```

You will receive the updated **ncount** value in the **countChange** event like this. (Note that you should have to declare **countChange** inside **NavComponent.ts**):

```
public countChange(newCount: number)
{
  console.log(newCount);
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use the   @ViewChild   decorator to get grip of objects inside the child, if you need them without it having to emit events...

Comment: Thanks @Obaid,but not working properly Can you please edit the  my above code

Comment: Can you specify the problem or problems you're having implementing the answer above? What's the error message on the console inside DevTools? @Haritha